# How can I Mechanize login to Facebook to scrape

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I want to login to a Facebook account through my code but the below code does not work. How is it possible?

This appears on my screen repeatedly, I want to login my account. Any help will be appreciated?
Please [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bdqG.png) for more details.

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
require 'csv'
require 'rubygems'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.log = Logger.new "mech.log"
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Linux Mozilla'
page = agent.get('https://www.facebook.com')
form1 = page.forms.first
form1.field_with(:name=>"email").value=email[enter image description here][1]
form1.field_with(:name=>"pass").value=password
pag=agent.submit form1, form1.buttons.first
```

Comment: I am unable to distinguish the error that you are talking about, can you please provide that or format your question so that it is clear to others?

Comment: If that facebook account has two-factor auth or requires browser approval then the facebooking scraping there won't work.

Comment: I have shared my console image through image link please verify and answer me anyone, (http://i.stack.imgur.com/0bdqG.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> agent = Mechanize.new
> agent.user_agent_alias = 'Android'
> login_page = agent.get('https://m.facebook.com/')
> login_form = agent.page.form_with(:method => 'POST')
> login_form.email = 'email'
> login_form.pass = 'password'
> agent.submit(login_form)
> ```

this would be help you....

Comment: @Maheshkumar.J please up vote the answer. Thank you.

Comment: i don't know how to vote this, can you please explain about, how to vote this?

Comment: @Maheshkumar.J please click on up arrow to up vote the answer